# MongoDB to return formatted object when no results can be found

Tags: mongodb, pipeline, aggregation

I have the following stage in my `MongoDB` aggregation pipeline that returns the qty and sum of sales, which works fine:

```
{
  $lookup: {
    from: 'sales',
    let: { part: '$_id' },
    pipeline: [
        { $match: { $and: [{ $expr: { $eq: ['$partner', '$$part'] } }] } },
        { $group: { _id: null, qty: { $sum: 1 }, soldFor: { $sum: '$soldFor' } } },
        { $project: { _id: 0, qty: 1, soldFor: 1 } }],
    as: 'sales'}},
    { $unwind: { path: '$sales', preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true } },
    { $project: { _id: 1, sales: 1 }
}
```

However, if there are no sales, then the `$project` projection returns an empty sales object, but what I'd really like is it to return a completed object, but with 0 - like this:

```
{
  sales: {
    qty: 0,
    soldFor: 0
  }
}
```

Comment: Take a look at `$ifNull` that should do the trick. See the doc:  https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/ifNull/

Comment: Thanks @Flo - that worked a treat!

Answer (score 1):

You can use `$cond` operator here

```
{
  "$project": {
    "_id": 1,
    "sales": {
      "$cond": [
        { "$eq": [{ "$size": "$sales" }, 0] },
        {
          "sales": {
            "qty": 0,
            "soldFor": 0
          }
        },
        "$sales"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```